# Вывод определенного текста при выборе нескольких radio

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Нужно чтобы при выборе определенного набора радиокнопок выводился нужный текст

Пример:

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group_1">Радио 1</input>
  <input type="radio" name="group_1">Радио 2</input>
</div>
    
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group_2">Радио 3</input>
  <input type="radio" name="group_2">Радио 4</input>
</div>

<div id="text"></div
```

И при выборе например 1 и 3 радио должен происходить вывод текста. Также и при выборе 2 и 3 или 1 и 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил

```js
let textObj = {
  '13': '<span style="color: red;">Text 13</span>',
  '23': '<span style="color: green;">Text 23</span>',
  '14': '<span style="color: green;">Text 14</span>',
  '24': '<span style="color: green;">Text 24</span>',
};
let textRadioObj = {
  '0': '<span style="color: red;">Aloha 1</span>',
  '1': '<span style="color: green;">Aloha 2</span>',
};

$('#click_me').click(function() {
  let textName = '';
  let textButtonArr = [];
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      textName += $(this).data("id");
      textButtonArr.push($(this).parent().text());
    }
  });
  if (textObj[textName]) {
    $('#text').html(textObj[textName]);
  }
  
  $.each( textButtonArr, function( key, value ) {
    $('#text_button_' + key).html(textRadioObj[key] + value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="1" name="group_1"></input>Радио 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="2" name="group_1"></input>Радио 2
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="3" name="group_2"></input>Радио 3
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="4" name="group_2"></input>Радио 4
  </label>
</div>
<button id="click_me">Click ME</button>

<div id="text"></div>
<div id="text_button_0"></div>
<div id="text_button_1"></div>
```

Рад помочь

Comment: Это подходит, но можно ли сделать чтобы текст выводился при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: Появился еще вопрос. Как можно вывести в результате html код и названия выбранных radio?

Comment: к примеру вместо текста Text 13 я хочу вставить html код. А по поводу названий: когда нажимается кнопка помимо нужного текста чтобы выводилось и названия выбранных чекбоксов. Как пример нажимается кнопки и выводится такой результат: Название выбранного чекбокса 1, Название выбранного чекбокса 2 и текст (желательно чтобы в нем можно было использовать html)

Comment: можно ли сделать 2 div'a для названий radio? Первый для первого radio, а второй для второго?

Comment: Простите что достаю, но можно ли вставить какой-либо текст или html-код перед или после названия radio. к примеру когда я нажал на кнопку и выводится результат чтобы перед названием радио можно было написать любой текст, или вставить хтмл кол. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Там для двух радио нужно два разных текста

Comment: а этот код можно использовать только для 2 радио или там можно вставить любое количество? let textRadioObj = {
  '0': '<span style="color: red;">Aloha 1</span>',
  '1': '<span style="color: green;">Aloha 2</span>',
};

Comment: Тут по сути весь код с небольшими изменениями можно использовать для любого количества radiobutton.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как это можно сделать?

Comment: Создай пожалуйста новый вопрос используя мой html. И сформулируй его хорошо, я решу )))

Comment: Создал. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Answer (score -2):

type=radio предусматривает выбор одного из группы вариантов. если вам нужно несколько из группы: то необходимо использовать checkbox. например так:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["checkboxInput"])) {
    if (in_array("value1",$_POST["checkboxInput"])) {
        echo "This is value 1<br/>";
    }
    if (in_array("value2",$_POST["checkboxInput"])) {
        echo "This is value 2<br/>";
    }
    if (in_array("value3",$_POST["checkboxInput"])) {
        echo "This is value 3<br/>";
    }
    if (in_array("value4",$_POST["checkboxInput"])) {
        echo "This is value 4<br/>";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxInput[]" value="value1">Value 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxInput[]" value="value1">Value 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxInput[]" value="value1">Value 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxInput[]" value="value1">Value 1<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Upd:
если 2 группы (см. комментарии), то код может выглядеть так:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["radioGroup1"]) || isset($_POST["radioGroup2"])) {
        echo "Group 1 value: ".$_POST["radioGroup1"]."<br/>";
        echo "Group 2 value: ".$_POST["radioGroup2"];
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="radio1">Радио 1</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="radio2">Радио 2</input>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="radio3">Радио 3</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="radio4">Радио 4</input>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Смысл писать столько `in_array`, когда первым аргументом, можно передать массив значений: `in_array(array('value1','value2','value3'), $_POST['checkboxInput']);` или наоборот `$_POST['checkboxInput']` - первым аргументом, для поиска в массиве на сервере.

Comment: там не одна группа, а две разных, и должен выбираться один из вариантов из группы 1 и группы 2

Comment: Я так понимаю вопрос конкретно про checkbox(

Comment: @user288458, дополнил ответ